# Add CNAME entry in which zone?

Tags: iis, dns, windows-server-2012-r2

There is an article on [Run Multiple Websites on the Same Port and IP Address on IIS](http://Run%20Multiple%20Websites%20on%20the%20Same%20Port%20and%20IP%20Address%20on%20IIS). So in my Windows Server 2012 R2, I installed DNS Server. However there is no zone by default.

But according to the [link](http://Run%20Multiple%20Websites%20on%20the%20Same%20Port%20and%20IP%20Address%20on%20IIS), I want to run multiple websites on the same port and IP address on IIS. After I edited site bindings on IIS. All I have to do is to add an alias for the server (A or CNAME) to DNS that specifies the IP address or the name of the web server.

Now I want to follow the example to add an entry to the zone. The below image is from the link. It has two zones. One is `_msdcs` and the other one is something I don't know.

[image]

However my DNS server doesn't have zone yet. I guess that I must create zones.then add the CNAME entry.

My question is which zone can I add the CNAME entry?
Or it doesn't matter in any primary zone?

Comment: Is this just a local test bed, or are you planning to use publicly registered domain names for these websites?

Comment: @CB_Ron, it is in the company's network. I can't access the web sites from my home. But in the company, everybody should can access the sites.

Comment: Okay. Does the company have an existing DNS server? If so, that's where the DNS records need to go. Otherwise, anyone who wants to access your websites will have to add your DNS server to their network config on their workstation.

Comment: @CB_Ron, My Windows Server hosts several web sites, I downloaded DNS from Server Management Tools. So you meant the DNS should be the one in company IT side rather than my Windows Server's DNS, right? The [link](http://woshub.com/run-multiple-websites-on-the-same-port-and-ip-address-on-iis/) is not clear about which DNS. Could you please read it?

Comment: It should definitely be your company IT DNS server. The `CNAME`s can go in an existing zone on that server; they don't have to go into a new one. However, there needs to be at least one host a.k.a. `A` record that points to the webserver. The `CNAME`s should all point to that as the target host.

Comment: @CB_Ron, thanks for the patience. I am not strong on DNS, one more question. Can we use `Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` file in Windows instead of IT DNS server?

Comment: That will only work on the machine that the `hosts` file is edited on. So if you want the whole company to access these sites, then a `hosts` file would have to be placed on each one. Better to use your IT DNS server.

Comment: @CB_Ron, please convert your comments to an answer then I can mark it.

Comment: Done! And thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should definitely be your company IT DNS server. The `CNAME`s can go in an existing zone on that server; they don't have to go into a new one. However, there needs to be at least one host a.k.a. `A` record that points to the webserver. The `CNAME`s should all point to that as the target host.

Answer (score -1):

For example, if you need to access a website from [www.test.com](http://www.test.com).
Then you can create a forward lookup zone.

[image]

Then you need to create a A record to map your IP address to your server
[image]

Now you can right click blank place->create Alias(CNAME) to map your A record to CNAME

[image]

Finally, you only have to set IIS binding and access the website

Comment: With the DNS server on the same machine as the website(s), and none of the expected users using that server for their DNS, this will not be very useful to the OP.